# HTML STRING TO PLAIN TEXT

Tags: html, vb.net, text, character-encoding

I have a HTML TEXT
`&Ouml;z&uuml;rl&uuml;lerin Stihdam Nda Evde Tele &Ccedil;alışma`
when i am trying to convert it into plain text its giving me result --
Özürlülerin Stihdam Nda Evde Tele ÇalÄ±ÅŸma but the proper result is  "Özürlülerin Stihdam Nda Evde Tele Çalışma"

```
Dim strTitleSub as string = "&Ouml;z&uuml;rl&uuml;lerin Stihdam Nda Evde Tele &Ccedil;alışma"

        Dim strPlaintext As String = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(strTitleSub)
```

> The desire result is not coming, what should i do now?

Comment: sorry i am trying to convert it into Plain TEXT.

Comment: `ış` is still in UTF8 Turkish

Comment: Try "&Ouml;z&uuml;rl&uuml;lerin Stihdam Nda Evde Tele &Ccedil;al&#305;&#351;ma"